# What is the protein with the highest affinity to lactose?

Tags: protein-interaction

I was wondering: What is the protein with the highest affinity to lactose? Are there some databases with values for affinity?

Comment: About what kind of affinity are you thinking? Binding of the sugar? Or do you think about specificity of enzymes?

Comment: Galectins 1&3 perhaps

Comment: Did you make any attempt to find out the answer? If yes then please add that to the question. It is not appreciated that you ask others to do literature search for you.

Comment: Yes, I did some research. I found that galectin 1 & 3 had very high affinity but there were not specific to lactose. I found this website: http://www.bindingdb.org/bind/index.jsp